# How i can filter (hook) function inside Wordpress Class?

Tags: class, hook, wordpress, add-filter

I have a plugin example:

```
class ProductCustomPostType {
        function __construct() {
            ..
            add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', array( $this, 'managePostCustomColumns' ) );
            }

    function managePostCustomColumns( $column_name ){
    ...
    }
   }
```

I need to hook function managePostCustomColumns from functions.php with add_filter action.

How i can do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hook custom code when a filter is applied, you have to call:

```
add_filter( 'manage_posts_custom_column', array( $this, 'managePostCustomColumns' ) );
```

If you need to call all functions, hooked to a specific filer, use:

```
apply_filters('manage_posts_custom_column', 'column_name')
```

Comment: I have no right to change the plugin code. I can only create hook outside in theme file functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the link and look at comments too, answer is in comments. this might help you.

[Override plugin with functions.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26228/override-plugin-with-functions-php)

Comment: this is topic about functions but not functions in classes.